# What does Android use to disallow starting service in background?

Tags: android, service, background, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

I am trying to startService only while in foreground, but to determine foreground I use **Activity.onStart, this however is called sometimes when app is in background as per that piece of code that throws java.lang.IllegalStateException**: Not allowed to start service Intent when starting the service.

-- *concretly, when starting activity with screen off.*

Does anyone know what the actual check is? How can I "if" this, i.e. I need to && onStart with some processIsInForeground() to get true onStart

So far I have

```
val appProcesses = activityManager.runningAppProcesses
if (appProcesses == null) return false

val thisProcess = appProcesses.firstOrNull { it.processName == packageName }
if (thisProcess == null) return false

val isProcessForeground == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND
```

But this only works like 90% of the time, some times importance is IMPORTANCE_SERVICE, sometimes IMPORTANCE_TOP_SLEEPING

Also, docs say that api is mostly just for debug, etc.

Comment: "I am trying to startService only while in foreground" -- if your UI is in the foreground, why do you need a service?

Comment: @CommonsWare maybe he means foreground service?

Comment: No, Its a CallService which is started only while app is in foreground, when call state is idle (so started when ui in foreground, stopped when ui goes to background), however the service needs to setForeground during active call + not get stopped after going to background

Comment: tldr; I need the service started so my call endpoint is open, but only when ui in foreground, to save battery, but with option to not get stopped when ui going to background during active call

Comment: my issue anyways is that activity.onStart and whatever contextimpl uses does not match

Comment: None of this explains why you feel that you need a service.

Comment: I need to not get killed when going to background while call is active. Yes, I was thinking about having endpoint open in "my" class and only startForegroundService with "empty" service when call is active; only to signal to the OS I dont want to get killed. Is that what you meant?

Comment: "I need to not get killed when going to background while call is active" -- a service will not help you, as you are stopping the service when your UI goes to the background ("stopped when ui goes to background").

Comment: No no, there is a logic of `if callState == Active then no-op else stopSelf`. Please dont worry about the service. I just need Observable<Boolean> that represents when non-foreground service is able to be started without exception